# Increase the size of collapsing toolbar layout on scrolling

Tags: android, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to achieve an effect where the image view in `collapsingToolbarLayout` on start is at `250dp` and on scrolling up the image view becomes `400dp`. This is an example of the requirement:

[animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLQgr.jpg)

On start the fragment looks like : [image]

On up scroll the fragment looks like : [image]

I am using the following code right now, but only able to collapse the view into a toolbar, not exapnd the size:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_avatar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder_user"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:alpha="0.3"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this XML you are missing Recyclerview/NestedScrollView below AppBarlayout, which should have layout_behvaiour, which will make the AppBarLayout and CollapsingBarLayout expand and collapse. Try with that.

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior
```

Comment: what should the layout_behaviour be set as ?

Comment: did you use it in a recyvlerview or Nestedscrllview?

Comment: in a NestedScrollView. you can look at the whole code here - https://gist.github.com/fireballpoint1/037db313256a61913e330379f19280bc

Comment: Follow it https://techlabroid.com/collapsing-toolbar-like-whatsapp-profile-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Used the following code in `onCreate()` :

```kotlin
val wm = context!!.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

        dWidth = wm.defaultDisplay

        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_main_expanded, container, false)


        layout.appbar.post(Runnable {

            val heightPx: Int = dWidth.width * 1 / 3

            setAppBarOffset(heightPx)

        })

        layout.profile_avatar.layoutParams.height = dWidth.width
```

`setAppBarOffset(heightpx)` is the following:

```kotlin
private fun setAppBarOffset(offsetPx: Int) {

        val params = layout.appbar.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        val behavior = params.behavior as AppBarLayout.Behavior?
        behavior!!.onNestedPreScroll(layout.coordinator,layout.appbar,this!!.view!!,0,offsetPx,intArrayOf(0, 0),0)
    }
```